# Reserve Space for jquery dynamic generated text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a div element that contains a dynamically generated text, however, the text elements of moves and makes all the elements below it are pushed down every few seconds.

Please check out the jsfiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/akar5h/fpksmod2/22/ .

I checked out similar questions which said try out by making visiblity = hidden on that element , so I tried by adding a long dummy text  `{"content": "longtext12234" , "visiblity": "hidden"}`  every time i delete text , and make it visible before adding the dynamic word . but no effect ,

I think this has to befixed using jquery since its dynamic adding and deleting , I do not want any fixed values in px , since I want the site to be responsive (using bootstrap) .
Any suggestions ?

Comment: Set a `min-height` on the element? https://jsfiddle.net/f8yr4cwz/. You can still use the `min-height` in responsive CSS media queries

Comment: It's better to provide your code in a built-in snippet than in JSFiddle. [Know why](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Setting a `height` value will resolve the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rory McCrossan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519413/rory-mccrossan) said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69033639/reserve-space-for-jquery-dynamic-generated-text?answertab=active#tab-top) that setting a `min-height` constraints restricts the content height.